# Wrong color in progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a progress bar which starts as determinate with green color, than changes behavior and became red and indeterminate, finally in the last step returns determinate.
In the second step red color is correct but with the last step, the foreground color is wrong, it is brown instead of red.

[image: Progress bar with wrong color]

The progress bar in xaml file:

```
<Grid Margin="10,0" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progress_bar" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,38" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="progress_bar_text" Margin="300,2,300,40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >0% - Waiting to start...</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Then when the abort button is pressed:

```
private void Button_abort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    progress_bar.IsIndeterminate = true;
    progress_bar.Foreground = Brushes.Red;        
}
```

Finally when the task is terminated the task bar behavior returns determinate.

```
progress_bar.IsIndeterminate = false;
progress_bar.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

Why the progress bar is brown instead of red?

Comment: maybe because you are using the default windows 7 theme that washes out the color?

Comment: @DenisSchaf yes, I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Progressbar color is red on my system.Probably @DenisSchaf is right.I'm using Windows 10

Comment: *"the foreground color is wrong"* - transparency and gray background behind changes the color, but it's red. Not sure though how to painlessly deal with `ProgressBar`, does terminating takes long? I mean, do you really need to see interruption progress? You could just stop progress, but prevent starting until it's terminated.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this style in your code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Value" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" MinWidth="10" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Maximum}" Height="50">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Column="0" Width="{TemplateBinding Value}">
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This will overwrite the original control template and make the progressbar flat and the color will stay what you set it to be

Comment: did that help you at all or is your issue still present? @Cyr